# SQL Query - Complex query between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I currently have the 5 following tables. Each Site has (1 or Many) Project Managers as well as (1 or Many) Site_Supervisors. A Project Manager / Site Supervisor can be assigned to many sites

I currently have a working query:

```
SELECT Sites.Site_Name, Sites.Site_Street_Address, Sites.Site_Suburb, Sites.Site_State, Sites.Site_Postcode, Sites.Site_Region, Sites.Completed, Project_Managers.First_Name AS PM_First_Name, Project_Managers.Last_Name AS PM_Last_Name, Site_Supervisors.First_Name AS SS_First_Name, Site_Supervisors.Last_Name AS SS_Last_Name, Sites.Date_Started
FROM Site_Site_Supervisors INNER JOIN
Site_Supervisors ON Site_Site_Supervisors.Site_Supervisor_ID = Site_Supervisors.Site_Supervisor_ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
Sites ON Site_Site_Supervisors.Site_ID = Sites.Site_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
Project_Managers INNER JOIN
Site_Project_Managers ON Project_Managers.Project_Manager_ID = Site_Project_Managers.Project_Manager_ID ON 
Sites.Site_ID = Site_Project_Managers.Site_ID
WHERE (Sites.Completed = 0)
ORDER BY Sites.Site_Name
```

Which gives me the desired output, which i then work with in my code.

I am wanting to make a change to the query, where instead of outputting the:
Project_Managers.First_Name AS PM_First_Name
Project_Managers.Last_Name AS PM_Last_Name

instead i replace these with:
Project_Managers.First_Name where the corresponding Site_Project_Managers.Primary_Contact = True AS PM_First_Name
Project_Managers.Last_Name where the corresponding Site_Project_Managers.Primary_Contact = True AS PM_Last_Name
Project_Managers.First_Name where the corresponding Site_Project_Managers.Primary_Contact = False AS AssistantPM_First_Name
Project_Managers.Last_Name where the corresponding Site_Project_Managers.Primary_Contact = False AS AssistantPM_Last_Name

To perform this query is beyond my SQL skillset at this time, so i am hoping one of you can provide me with the correct query to use and or some guidance
Thanks

---

### Sites

```
[Site_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL (PK),
[Site_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Site_Street_Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Site_Suburb] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Site_State] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Site_Postcode] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Site_Region] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Date_Started] [datetime] NULL,
[Completed] [bit] NOT NULL
```

---

### Project_Managers

```
[Project_Manager_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL (PK),
[First_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Last_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Phone_Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Email_Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Currently_Employed] [bit] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Project_Managers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

---

### Site_Supervisors

```
[Site_Supervisor_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL (PK),
[First_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Last_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Phone_Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Email_Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Currently_Employed] [bit] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Site_Supervisors_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

---

### Site_Project_Managers

```
[Site_ID] [int] NOT NULL (PK),
[Project_Manager_ID] [int] NOT NULL (PK),
[Primary_Contact] [bit] NULL,
[Alerts] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Site_Project_Managers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

---

### Site_Site_Supervisors

```
[Site_ID] [int] NOT NULL (PK),
[Site_Supervisor_ID] [int] NOT NULL (PK),
[Primary_Contact] [bit] NULL,
[Alerts] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Site_Site_Supervisors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: Project_Managers.Last_Name where the corresponding Site_Project_Managers.Primary_Contact = True AS PM_First_Name --- I'm assuming that "First_Name" at the end should be "Last_Name"?

Comment: Yeah it is. thanks. i have edited the post.

Comment: Is it Mysql? Can you tag with relevant tags ?

Comment: How can we identify the assistant project managers ?

Comment: They are in the project managers table but with an attribute of False in the Primary_Contact value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed you are using MySql and you may use the CASE or inline IF ELSE to get the desired output that you want

```
SELECT Sites.Site_Name, 
    Sites.Site_Street_Address, 
    Sites.Site_Suburb, 
    Sites.Site_State, 
    Sites.Site_Postcode, 
    Sites.Site_Region, 
    Sites.Completed, 
    CASE    Site_Project_Managers.Primary_Contact
            WHEN true THEN Project_Managers.First_Name
    END AS PM_First_Name,
    CASE    Site_Project_Managers.Primary_Contact
            WHEN true THEN Project_Managers.Last_Name
    END AS PM_Last_Name,
    CASE    Site_Project_Managers.Primary_Contact
            WHEN false THEN Project_Managers.First_Name
    END AS AssistantPM_First_Name,
    CASE    Site_Project_Managers.Primary_Contact
            WHEN false THEN Project_Managers.Last_Name
    END AS AssistantPM_Last_Name,
    Site_Supervisors.First_Name AS SS_First_Name, 
    Site_Supervisors.Last_Name AS SS_Last_Name,
    Sites.Date_Started
FROM Site_Site_Supervisors 
INNER JOIN Site_Supervisors 
ON Site_Site_Supervisors.Site_Supervisor_ID = Site_Supervisors.Site_Supervisor_ID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Sites 
ON Site_Site_Supervisors.Site_ID = Sites.Site_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Project_Managers 
INNER JOIN Site_Project_Managers 
ON Project_Managers.Project_Manager_ID = Site_Project_Managers.Project_Manager_ID 
ON Sites.Site_ID = Site_Project_Managers.Site_ID
WHERE (Sites.Completed = 0)
ORDER BY Sites.Site_Name
```

Comment: It is actually MS SQL 2008 we are using, sorry for the missing tag

Comment: With some very minor changes this still works in MS-SQL! Thanks